# Distinguish types of on-disk models

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

Tensorflow has several [types of model formats](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_saved_model):

> 1. TensorFlow SavedModel 2. Frozen Model 3. Session Bundle 4. Tensorflow Hub module

How can you distinguish between them on-disk? (to later use with tensorflowjs-converter)

And how is each model created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, there are a LOT of different model types, and they all have good reasons.  I'm not going to claim that I have perfect clarity of each, but here's what I know (I think I know).

- The `.pb` file:  PB stands for protobuff or Protocol Buffer.  This is the model structure, generally without the trained weights and is stored in a binary format.
- The `.pbtxt` file: Nonbinary of the `pb` file for human reading.
- Protobuff files that aren't frozen will need a checkpoint `.ckpt` file, too.  The Checkpoint file is the missing set of weights that the `pb` needs.
- The `.h5` file:  The model + weights from a Keras save
- The `.tflite` file would be a TensorflowLite model
- *Frozen Model*: A frozen model combines the `pb` with the weights file, so you don't have to manage two of them.  Usually, this means adding the word `frozen` to the filename.  I'm sure this can be inferred when loading the file, but on disk they are a bit more on the honor system and no `ckpt` file.  This strips out extraneous graph info; it's basically like the "Production Ready" version of the model.
- Session Bundle:  Are a directory.  They are nolonger used, and rare.
- Tensorflow Hub Module: These are pre-existing popular models that are very likely already exported to TFJS and don't require you to manually convert them.  I assume they are supported for Google's benefit, more so than ours.  But it's nice to know if you use hub, you can always convert it.

A multi-exported grouping of files looks like this image.   From here, you can see quite a few that you could turn into TFJS.

[image: Different TF file types]

Comment: Thanks! After conversion, there's also the `model.json` with related `group?-shard?of?`.